# DatePickerDialog in android application

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog

I’m using DatePickerDialog in my android application.
Now this picker looks like this:

[image]

What should I do, to make this picker looking like this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: which picker you want look like another first like second or second should look like first ?

Comment: why on earth would you want it to look the second? You can probably change the style and make it happen though

Comment: use this lib then for back compatibiity https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: I want picker like this: http://goo.gl/uGDc2X because, in my opinion, usability of that picker is much better...